# Is this method recommended for query strings in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express

Currently making an application which needs to parse a query string with repeated values. Right now what I'm doing is something like this.

`GET /api/titles?status=green&status=red` which returns an array in the `req.query.status` like this `req.query.status: ["green", "red"]`.

This can get cumbersome on the client side with a long url string when many fields are required. I've discovered that this works as well. `GET /api/titles?status=green,red` which returns something like this `req.query.status: "green,red"`. I can then split this string into an array by running `req.query.status.split(",")`. This results in an array with the same results to `["green", "red"]`.

My question is this a recommended way of doing this? Are there any security risks for running this?

Comment: `"Are there any security risks"?` Sure, if you are using the raw string values to perform CRUD operations against a database, or using the raw string values to perform IO operations, or using the raw string values to modify AD... the list can go on and on. What is your specific question and concern?

Comment: My concern is whether or not the second method is considered bad practice. I'm still a junior dev so I'd like to know what best practices are in the context of nodejs

Comment: There is no sequrity difference how to pass data but it is significant how data will be processed after receiving and decomposing by spliting by comma if such used. Some tools maps data structure to query line may be you need to search them.

Comment: Have you considered using `POST` instead of `GET`?

Comment: @robertklep The context in this was to quickly retrieve object keys from a specific model

Comment: Fair enough, but, using your own words, _"this can get cumbersome ...when many fields are required"_.  FWIW, Express uses [`qs`](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) to parse query string, which could also help you on the client side (specifically, [`qs.stringify()`](https://github.com/ljharb/qs#stringifying)).